# Timed out Issue with Asp.net webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I have a asp.net web service and it has multiple web method.

In my client side it has timed out configuration like,

```
 <binding name="TestWebServiceSoap" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:50:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
```

When i have to call the web service, i am creating a new instance of the web service once,

```
 TestWebServiceSoapClient objWebServiceClient = objWebServiceClient = new TestWebServiceSoapClient(strEndPointName, strEndPointAddress);
```

> Where **strEndPointName** is the endpoint name and the
> **strEndPointAddress** is the end point address

And then call multiple web method based on this instance (without creating a new instance for every web method) Like,

> ```
> objWebServiceClient.TestWebMethodone(string parameter1,string parameter2);
> objWebServiceClient.TestWebMethodtwo(string parameter1,string parameter2);
> objWebServiceClient.TestWebMethodthree(string parameter1,string parameter2);
> ```

and so on.

Now My question is,

> Does the timed out configuration for the end point is applied for each
> web method separately?
>
> That is does TestWebMethodone,TestWebMethodtwo,TestWebMethodthree  will get the timed out value separately for data transfer operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the timed out configuration for the end point is applied for each web method separately?
>   That is does TestWebMethodone,TestWebMethodtwo,TestWebMethodthree will get the timed out value separately for data transfer operation?

Yes, each operation on webservice will get its own timeout.

Comment: Thanks. but do you have any reliable source that describes about this. Don't take it in another way pls. i appreciate your answer.  @No One

Comment: i can tell you this with my experience.